# How to solve date group by in Data Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, wcf, gridview

Hi I can able Get result into Datatable from WCF(API) and Bind to Grid Like:

DataTable dt

```
     EventStart               |   EventEnd      
    =============================================
  1/9/2015 1:00:00 Pm      |   1/9/2015 1:15:00 Pm 
  1/9/2015 3:00:00 Pm      |   1/9/2015 4:15:00 Pm 
  13/10/2015 10:00:00 Am   |   13/10/2015 11:15:00 Am 
  13/10/2015 1:00:00 Pm    |   13/10/2015 2:15:00 Pm
```

But I want Result in another DataTable dt2 Like this

```
   Date                     |  Total Minutes
==============================================
  1/9/2015                  |  150 Minutes
  13/10/2015                |  150 Minutes
```

Anybody can Help Please.... I am new in LINQ....

Answer (score 1):

Skip the datatables, and just bind directly to the LINQ result, like this:

```
Grid.DataSource=result
  .GroupBy(x=>x.EventStart.Date,x=>(x.EventEnd-x.EventStart).TotalMinutes)
  .Select(x=>new {Date=x.Key,TotalMinutes=x.Sum()});
```

This assumes that WCF returns something IEnumerable, that has an EventStart and EventEnd (Like an array, List, IList, Collection, etc)